# What different experiences bonuses are available and how do you get them?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

When you complete a game, there are a variety of experience bonuses that accumulate into a multiplier and increase the amount of experience you get in a variety of areas of both game development and individual experience levels for your employees.

[image]

Such bonuses include;

- New Topic
- New Combo
- Good Management

What are these different experience bonuses, how many different bonuses are available and how do you trigger them?

Comment: There's a game called game dev tycoon? Can you feel the META

Comment: @AliceRees you should [read how they attempt to deal with piracy](http://www.greenheartgames.com/2013/04/29/what-happens-when-pirates-play-a-game-development-simulator-and-then-go-bankrupt-because-of-piracy/) ;)

Comment: read the post. Bought the game immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guarantee that this is not an exhaustive list, but it's a start. Feel free to edit if you find any more bonuses to add.

*New Topic* - Create a game using a topic you haven't used previously

*New Combo* - Create a game using a topic/ genre combo you haven't used previously

*Great Combo* - Create a game with a topic/ genre combo that is "great" (common sense combinations like Fantasy/RPG)

*Trend Match* - Create a game that matches the random "market trend" event. These suggest you to develop a game that meets a certain criterion (genre, topic, audience, etc.)

*Good Management* - When you are developing a medium or large project (by yourself or with the help of a publisher), you have to assign employees to different parts of the game (engine, AI, graphics, etc). If you don't push any employees beyond 100% effort, you will earn this bonus.

Comment: Regarding "Good Management" - I have had instances where I've pushed employees up to 110% and still got this bonus so there may be a bit of leeway